# Unknown gedit fstab failure

Tags: fstab, gedit

Recently I entered;

`sudo gedit /etc/fstab`

In responce I got,

```
(gedit:66385): dconf-WARNING **: 22:49:56.775: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)

(gedit:66385): dconf-WARNING **: 22:49:56.778: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)

(gedit:66385): dconf-WARNING **: 22:49:56.890: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)

(gedit:66385): dconf-WARNING **: 22:49:56.890: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)

(gedit:66385): dconf-WARNING **: 22:49:56.890: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)

** (gedit:66385): WARNING **: 08:22:33.104: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported

(gedit:66385): dconf-WARNING **: 08:22:33.113: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)*
```

Only physical change to machine, since I last used successfully, is shifting my home folder to an SSD drive partition. An effort to save data should my system melt down.

Should this have affected this or is it something else.
New install of Ubuntu 22.04 fully updated, upgraded  & refreshed.

Casual observation is that I have noticed some latency in apps opening and cursor responses even text highlighting delays till after I release the mouse button.

Looking for avenues to investigate as to cause of fstab edit?

Cheers

Virtual novice, Brucie...

Comment: try "sudo -E gedit /etc/fstab"

Answer (score 0):

In your `~/.bashrc`, add

```
export EDITOR=$(type -p gedit)
export VISUAL=$(type -p gedit)
```

Then, `source .bashrc`.

Now, you can `sudoedit /etc/fstab`. Read `man sudoedit`.

Here's what `sudoedit` does:

1. Authenticate the user (like `sudo`).
2. As `root` make a temporary copy of the file, that the user can edit.
3. As the user, invoke `$VISUAL` to edit the temporary file.
4. When the editor exits, if the file was changed, as `root`, `sudoedit` copies the temporary file back to target file.

I've successfully used `sudoedit` with  `emacsclient`, `vim`, `vi`, `nano`, and `ed` as the `$VISUAL`.

Comment: Sorry this seems a little out of context for me. Can you be a bit more specific...

Comment: Rather than spend time explaining why `root` can't access a screen owned by `$USER`, and why it a Well Known Bad Idea (security) to mess with the system to allow this, I used my 65 years computing experience to offer a way you can accomplish the task you failed at. How is that "out of context"? Which part(s) of my answer needs more specification?

Comment: Wow super ego trip. Thanks but no thanks.

Comment: Calling me names :-( I showed you how to solve your problem, showed you how it works, showed the several editors I've used `sudoedit` with. I responded, politely, I thought, to your "out of context...be more specific"  comnent. Rather than address the questions I asked ("How is that "out of context"? Which part(s) of my answer needs more specification?'), you chose an Ad Hominen (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem) response. I now understand that you don't want my help. Thanks for playing.